# permalink structure for single-{post-type}.php in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have tried many ways to display my custom post type as `single-{post-type}` and finally it works nicely once i used:

```
'rewrite'=> false,
```

before that, i used

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'custom-post-type' )
```

but never works for me. Don't know where i made mistake. Right now i should feel happy cos its working without any error. But have a small confusion for the permalink because its display:

1. `localhost/myblog/?news=breaking-news`
2. ***instead of:*** `localhost/myblog/news/breaking-news`

anyone please provide me some idea how to get link like: `localhost/myblog/news/breaking-news`

my permalink structure selected:

> http//myblog/sample-post/

and its working for other post types.

Answer (score 0):

Like you wrote above, you should use `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'custom-post-type' )` when registering your post type.